# How to omit module prefix?

Tags: python

I am very new to python, I have a simple question.

For example

If I do

```
import A
```

then I can use `A.b()`.
I am wondering, how to omit `A` in `A.b()`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use `b` from module `A`:

```
from A import b
```

If you want to rename it:

```
from A import b as my_b
```

If you need several objects:

```
from A import b, c, d
```

If you need everything:

```
from A import *
```

---

About the `import *` option, please do read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).
It's rather short, but tl;dr: do not import everything from a module by `from A import *`.
If you really need everything from the module, or a very big part of its content, prefer the normal import, possibly with renaming:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that you absolutely shouldn't use `from A import *`. It's just that you should be careful when you do so. For example, it was recommended to me in a Tk tutorial that I use `from tkinter import *; from tkinter import ttk` for themed widgets, as `tk` and `ttk` are so easy to confuse. I almost always do so when using `tkinter`. (I only didn't put the two imports on separate lines because I don't know how to do so in a comment).

Comment: @IsaacSaffold That is rather true, but the care needed is quite painful. Anyway, the post I linked covers this way better than I could.

Comment: Once you do `from os import *` and spend hours debugging because your calls to `open` don't work anymore you'll never use wildcard imports again.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold importing all is like [`using namespace std` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: @Matthias I never use wildcard imports for modules like `os` for that very reason. As I said, I am cautious.

Answer (score 8):

Since `A` is a module, you can do:

```
from A import b 

b()
```

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered, but one thing to note when using imports is that

```
from module import foo
```

and

```
import module
```

Are absolutely the same, as far as memory and performance is concerned. In either case, the `module` is compiled and loaded into `sys.modules`. The only difference is what is brought into your namespace. In the first case, it is `foo`. In the second case, it is `module`.

Since the other answers do not explain why using `from module import *` is bad, this is the reason: `*` will import *everything* into your namespace for direct use. This is not a good idea unless *you know what you are doing*. Name clashes are definitely possible, especially when importing multiple large modules.

This may be a matter of opinion, but I believe `import module` followed by `module.foo()` is safer and gives the reader a better idea about that method/attribute, where it came from, and what it is doing. Readability matters!